# Disable specific items in a CheckboxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am running through a set of data, which will populate a CheckBoxList. I want to display all the items in the list but certain ones will be disabled as they don't qualify (their status equals Inactive). How do I set an item to disabled (Enabled = false) in the code behind like this?

```
if (node.SelectSingleNode("Status") == "Inactive")
   {
     customerList.Items.Add(new ListItem(displayName, displayValue)); // DISABLED
   }
else
   {
     customerList.Items.Add(new ListItem(displayName, displayValue));  // ENABLED
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (node.SelectSingleNode("Status") == "Inactive")
   {
     customerList.Items.Add(new ListItem{Name=displayName, Value= displayValue, Enabled= false}); // DISABLED
   }
else
   {
     customerList.Items.Add(new ListItem(displayName, displayValue));  // ENABLED
   }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but this may work:

```
customerList.Items.Add(new ListItem(displayName, displayValue)); // DISABLED
ListItem li = customerList.Items.FindByValue(displayValue);
li.Enabled = false;
```

UPDATED to use FindByValue

Comment: This didn't work for me at first but then I changed it to "FindByValue" instead of "FindItemByValue" and it worked. Thank you.